# PHP + cURL Request to Server - Requires Certificate/NSSDB

Tags: php

Our system needs to make a cURL call from PHP to a third party server. The third party server requires us to include a certificate with the request for authentication. Currently our requests are returning:

HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 0: NSS: client certificate not found
or
NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)

Server is standard Fedora 15 LAMP stack.

Answer (score 2):

I found the below at http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/stuck-with-php-curl-and-ssl-certificates-322684/ which looks like it will suit your needs, specifically `CURLOPT_SSLCERT, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, CURLOPT_SSLKEY`

```
    $url            =       "https://www.bla.com/foo"; // onramp url 

    $clientcert    =       $diagno_libdir."/exported-with-private-key.pem"; 
    $keyfile        =       $diagno_libdir."/clientkey.key"; 
    $challenge      =       "nightmare"; 

    print "<bR><BR>$challenge<br><br>"; 
    print "<bR><BR>$keyfile<br><br>"; 

    $header = Array(); 
    $header[] = "Content-Type: multipart/related \r\n"; 
    $header[] = "type=text/xml \r\n"; 
    $header[] = "boundary=--someBoundaryValue-- \r\n"; 
    $header[] = "start=ebXML_Message_Header \r\n"; 
    $header[] = $iptest; 

    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $clientcert); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, $challenge); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYTYPE, 'PEM'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, $keyfile); 

    $ret = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize this question was asked a year+ ago, but since I found it because I ran into (I think) the same issue today:

My issue was that the certificate I was trying to use was signed by a Certificate Authority (CA) that wasn't on the list of CA's accepted by the server.  This was verified using openssl.

1. `openssl s_client -connect host:443 -showcerts | more` (which lists the accepted CA certs)
2. `openssl x509 -in mycert.crt -noout -text | more` (which shows who signed my cert...)

If the CA from 2. isn't in the list found in 1., then you're not going to be able to complete the SSL authentication.